# How to uninstall JavaFx from Windows machine if previously deleted Oracle install directory?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, uninstallation

Before going to the Add or Remove Programs dialog to properly uninstall JavaFx, I accidentally deleted the Oracle install directory and removed it from the Recycle Bin (*cue laugh-track*). Now, when I go to remove JavaFx, I get the following error dialog,

[image]

And after I click "OK", it rolls back the uninstall. Ut-oh! So, how do I uninstall JavaFx now?

Answer (score 2):

Try the 30 day trial of http://www.revouninstaller.com/ ive used it to fix things with broken installers before.

Comment: you will most likely need 2 things, something to remove the installation from your registry and to do a scan to remove any scraps left in other directories relating to the install. A tedious task without a tool, thats the only reason i recommend something like revo uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

A System Restore fixed the problem.